# iphone image merging

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch

i want to merge multiple images ina single image,by using a button click>my problem is ,,if the user touch a image in tableview ,the coresponding image have to merge with the main image in the next page..how can we done this?
[image]

this is the main image in the page![this the the uppercloth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KstjO.png)

i have to fix the upper cloth in the caricature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext, then call drawAtPoint method of the images, then use UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext to get the merged image. Something like this(Not checked, just wrote from memory..Syntax errors possible..Correct yourselves..)

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourFirstImage.size);
[yourFirstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];
[yourSecondImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

UIImage *mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: ,thnku,another doubt,i want to create buttons in a subview of this view,if i tap the button in subview the image of the view changes is it possible?